# Error Reading Values in a Array of Structures

Tags: c, gcc

```
struct book{
    char name;
    float price;
    int pages;
};
struct book b[4];
int i;

for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    printf("Enter name, price and pages in the book:\n");
    scanf("%c %f %d", &b[i].name, &b[i].price, &b[i].pages);
}
```

when I run the above code, it asks for all three variables only in first iteration and for the next iteration onwards I can only enter first value(i.e. char). I know there is something wrong with the float variable here since I am getting random huge values when trying to display it. 
How do I solve it and what actually is going on?

I using gcc on linux.

A detailed explanation is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try adding a space before '%c'. `scanf(" %c %f %d", &b[i].name, &b[i].price, &b[i].pages);`

Comment: Is the name of your book really just a single char? In that case, entering "Moby-Dick" will try to convert "oby" into a floating-point number. But even if you enter a single char, the `scanf("%c", ...)` will read the new-line character at the end of the line. And once you've tripped, you never get back on track. I suggest to take a two-level approach here: `fgets` a line, then parse it with `sscanf`. Make use of the return values of these functions and report and handle errors.

Comment: @MOehm Using an array of characters and passing a %s instead of %c works good. And as Abhay Aravinda said, adding an extra space works as well. I want to know what's happening.

Comment: @AbhayAravinda Can you please explain what's happening?

Comment: Whitespaces are also sometimes read as a character. Adding a space before `%c` or `%s` prevents this from happening.

Comment: What's happening is that the `%c` format in `scanf`, unlike nearly all other formats, does not ignore white-space before conversion. It reads the next character, period. That together with the fact that `scanf` does not really distinguish between spaces, tabs and new-lines makes `scanf` unsuitable for line-based input formats, except perhaps the most basic ones.